# Auto Adjust height of multiline editor for in MVC using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-core-mvc

I have below editorfor which is multiline, I need to auto adjust height when user starts adding multiple email address in separate lines using bootstrap. Any code example is highly appreciated.

Model:

```
     [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] 
     public string AdditionalEmailAddressesText { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalEmailAddressesText, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AdditionalEmailAddressesText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Strings.Porting_AdditionalEmailAddressesSubtext } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalEmailAddressesText)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `textarea` tag, there's no `auto-height` attribute to make it adjust the height automatically. And for the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]`  annotation, it doesn't provide feature for setting rows and colums as well. So you have to write script code to add `oninput` event listener to change the style.

```
@model NewEvent

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "placeholder" } })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new {cols = 2, rows = 5})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Body)
        </div>
    </div>
    @section scripts {

    <script>
        $("#Body").each(function () {
          this.setAttribute("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
        }).on("input", function () {
          this.style.height = "auto";
          this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
        });
    </script>
    }
```